# C++ Programming, read line from string

Tags: c++, string, scanf

I need to read line by line from a string. I tried the following code but I am getting a error while there are empty lines in between and not able to find what I am doing wrong.

```
void ReadAllLine(char *szCont)
{
    int rdl = 0; /* read length */
    int len = 0; /* total length */
    char szLine[512] = {};

    len = strlen(szCont);

    int tl = 0; /* temp len */
    while(rdl < len)
    {  
       sscanf(szCont + rdl, "%512s\r\n", szLine);
       rdl += strlen(szLine) + 1;
       printf("%s\n", szLine);
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Input :

```
#Tag01
ENTRY01
ENTRY02

#Tag02
ENTRY11
ENTRY22

#Tag03
ENTRY31
ENTRY32
```

Output :

```
#Tag01
ENTRY01
ENTRY02
#Tag02
ENTRY11
ENTRY22
#Tag03
3
ENTRY31
ENTRY32
```

why is the 3 getting printed here?

Note : Every line is terminated with Windows notation (\r\n) and there are no spacebars before or after any line. The input is read from a file and passed to this function.

Comment: `\r\n` is not "Unix notation", it is Windows'. Unix-like systems use `\n`.

Comment: @Jongware ok corrected

Comment: You say there're no whitespaces but `\r\n` are not whitespace characters? FYI [all of those are whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is your code made even more minimal to reproduce the issue

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

void ReadAllLine(const char *szCont)
{
    int rdl = 0; /* read length */
    int len = 0; /* total length */
    char szLine[512] = {};

    len = strlen(szCont);

    while(rdl < len)
    {
       sscanf(szCont + rdl, "%s", szLine);
       rdl += strlen(szLine) + 1;
       printf("%s\n", szLine);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char *str ="\n\n#Tag02";
    ReadAllLine(str);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
#Tag02
2
```

The reason is quite simple. `sscanf` ignores whitespace characters until it finds non-whitespace characters to push in to the output string. Thus, when you call `sscanf(szCont + 0, "%s", szLine);` for the first time, it skips the 2 `\n`s occuring first and then moves on to pushing `#Tag02` into `szLine`. Now the value of `rdl = 0 + 7` since `strlen("#Tag02") = 6`. This means `szCont + rdl` would now be pointing to `2`, which gets printed in the next iteration.

The same issue occurs in your case too; your input has 2 `\n\n` ocurrings, once after `ENTRY02`, then after `ENTRY22`.

Comment: can you help me to change this code to read only non empty lines one by one?

Comment: You're using C in the name of C++ and that too incorrect C. When you're programming in C++, follow C++ way of doing things instead of sticking to old habits inherited from C. There're many questions in SO which demonstrates reading file line by line in C++. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/c-read-file-line-by-line) a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating carriage return (\r) and line feed (\n) both as line separators, this may vary from operating system to operating system (like windows, unix etc), so be careful, otherwise, the code looks ok. There should not be '3' coming as a separate line, unless you have some whitespace while inputting previous line.
Other option is to use fflush before printf statement as below:

```
fflush(stdout);
printf("%s\n", szLine);
```

Comment: Every line is terminated with unix notation (\r\n) and there are no white spaces before or after any line